# Is there are any implementations of stopwatch in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, stopwatch

I would like to run performance measurement for some critical functions on the website written on **TypeScript**.  I'm wondering if there is any implementation of **stopwatch** similar to .NET `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` class in **TypeScript**?

Comment: Have you found something in JavaScript that works? Because you can just use that in TypeScript. Otherwise this is off-topic, since asking for recommendations is off-topic, as are requests to find libraries.

Comment: There are some libraries written in JavaScript; I'm just curious if there are any in TypeScript.

Comment: Don't get hung up on the differences; by the time it gets to the browser, it's all JavaScript.

Comment: See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now

Answer (score 9):

Building off of [basarat's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390330/basarat) answer above, this is already built in to **console**.

```
console.time('myTask');
// code to time here
console.timeLog('myTask');
console.timeEnd('myTask');
```

Comment: This is a great solution. In Chrome I was getting an error when console.timeLog() was called. It seems that in Chrome calling console.timeEnd() deletes the timer. Deleting the console.timeLog() fixed my issue in Chrome.

--- Additional Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50524467/mytimer-dose-not-exist-in-console-timer

Comment: well, this does not return anything, how am I supposed to use it?

Answer (score 7):

I have a simple implementation [here](https://github.com/alm-tools/alm/blob/dec887d29d60aed6cfec1deee8bfe5c7d2bceb95/src/common/utils.ts#L458-L475):

```
/**
 * Simple timer
 */
export function timer() {
    let timeStart = new Date().getTime();
    return {
        /** <integer>s e.g 2s etc. */
        get seconds() {
            const seconds = Math.ceil((new Date().getTime() - timeStart) / 1000) + 's';
            return seconds;
        },
        /** Milliseconds e.g. 2000ms etc. */
        get ms() {
            const ms = (new Date().getTime() - timeStart) + 'ms';
            return ms;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
const howLong = timer();
// do some stuff
console.log(howLong.ms);
```

There are lots of other implementations out there as well as the built in `console.time` function you can look at.

Answer (score 2):

This stopwatch is written in `typescript` and comes with type definitions.
https://github.com/vcfvct/stopwatch-node

Comment: This solution is quite convenient, and the package only has dev dependencies, so it's quite slim.

Answer (score 0):

Since the OP asked specifically for something similar to .NET's Stopwatch, the `@tsdotnet/stopwatch` package might be a good option.

First, install package in your `npm` project: `npm i @tsdotnet/stopwatch`

Code example:

```
import Stopwatch from "@tsdotnet/stopwatch"

(async () => {
const stopwatch = Stopwatch.startNew();

    // Simulates a delay of 1000 milliseconds.
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));

    console.log(stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds);
})();
```

Please, notice that your `tsconfig.json` needs to be targeting at least `es2015` due to the use of promises in this example. This is not a requirement because of `@tsdotnet/stopwatch`.