# What is causing 'myTimer does not exist' error in console.timeEnd()?

Tags: javascript

I've created a demo for RxJS `scan()` method but unfortunately my timer doesn't work properly and I get this error: `Timer 'myTimer' does not exist`

```
console.time('myTimer');

let source = Rx.Observable
    .interval(100) // interval starts from 0
    .take(4)
    .scan((acc, val) => acc + val);

source.subscribe((value) => {
    console.timeEnd('myTimer');
    console.log('in next. Value: ', value);
});
```

[Here is a demo in JSBin.](https://jsbin.com/zenowa/edit?html,js,console)

[Here is a source that I Copy code from that.](https://codingblast.com/rxjs-operators/)

How can fix that issue?

Comment: You would start by putting your code in the question instead of in an external resource.

Comment: Hi! The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)). More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: How does the title *"Console.timer() dose not exist"* relate to the error message *"Timer 'myTimer' does not exist"*?

Answer (score 5):

You may be calling `timeEnd()` multiple times.

Once you've stopped the timer with `console.timeEnd("name")` it no longer exists when using chrome.

```js
console.time("myTimer");
for(var i=0;i<10000;i++){
}

console.timeEnd("myTimer"); // works
console.timeEnd("myTimer"); // displays an error (in chrome only)
```

Which is pretty much what your code is doing. The first time `subscribe` is called your timer outputs the amount of time since it ws started. On the 3 subsequent calls it does not work.

This behaviour is specific to Chrome, it works how you expect in both IE & Firefox.

Comment: Ok, But What should I do to it works like source code I Put in question?

Comment: It does not have a result like source code. you can see `reduce()` method example in https://codingblast.com/rxjs-operators/

Comment: @distance thats just the way chrome have chosent to implement that feature. You can see it works fine in IE how you had it, same for firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
console.time("myTimer")
```

at the start of your function in which you are using .timeEnd

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).